# Which one is correct?

Tags: style

This book will expand your knowledge of Italian food and allow you to surprise your friends and family with authentic home-cooked meals that taste delicious.

or

This book will expand your knowledge of Italian food and will allow you to surprise your friends and family with authentic home-cooked meals that taste delicious.

My doubt is, can I use will two times in the same paragraph?

Thanks

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. That being said, Writers.SE does not handle requests for rephrasing, nor "which of these two phrasings are better" questions - they don't fit our Q&A format well, and they're unlikely to be helpful to anybody besides the original poster. You can read more on this meta-post: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

My short answer: Either is fine. I'd probably use the version with two "will"s because the sentence is long enough that with only one the implied "re-use" of the first one could get lost.

It is true that in general one should be cautious about using the same word twice in one sentence. But that guideline is less important when talking about short common words, like "is" and "he" and "the" ... and "will".

In a very short sentence, it's common to drop the second "will" on a compound future-tense verb.

> Fine: Sally will stand and will give her speech.
>
> Better: Sally will stand and give her speech.

The second is correct because the "will" is understood to apply to both "stand" and "give". It is better because it avoids saying "will" twice in rapid succession.

But in your example, "expand" and "allow" are pretty far apart, and it is easier to see a reader losing track of that first "will". In that case not dropping the second "will" may make the sentence more clear.

Answer (score 0):

First version has a minor grammar error:

... and allow***s*** you ...

Apart from that, both are fine. I would probably use the second version.

I think both sentences are too similiar to use in the same paragraph.

Comment: Are you sure it should be allows?

Comment: If you opt not to use the second "will" then there is no requirement for "allow" to refer back to the first. So "This book allows you to ...". If you don't like "allows" then make the second "will" explicit as in your second version.

Comment: I think it's better with "allow" than "allows". With "allow", you're implying that the "will" applies to "allow" as well as "expand". We do this all the time. "Bob will run and jump." That is, he "will run" and "will jump". It's also legal with "allows", but then you're saying it "will expand", future, but it "allows", present. In this case it works either way.

Comment: Agreed. But then I would repeat will to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the first option over the second. That said, @Stephen has a point. If you include the "s" as he suggests, you will put the verb in present tense, if you leave off the "s", it will be a future tense verb which would likely be preferred.

Try to avoid using "will" twice, it makes the sentence flow better.

[Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41123/using-will-twice-in-a-sentence) is a link to an english.se question relating your question.

This answer is assuming that the OP's intended question was **"Can I use will two times in the same *sentence*?"** rather than **"Can I use will two times in the same *paragraph*?"**